# Panic exception when calculating cumulative evaluation for each group in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to calculate cumulative values (e.g. mean, number of unique, and mode) for each group, and some groups have only None.
When I calculate the values for a columns that doesn't have None, I get correct result. However, when I specify the columns that have only None in some groups, I get the below error.

```
PanicException: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: SchemaMisMatch(Borrowed("cannot unpack Series; data types don't match"))
```

How can I calculate the values?

For example,

```
pl_df = pl.DataFrame({'key': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2],
                      'col1': [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1],
                      'col2': [1, 2, None, 3, None, None, 3, 4, None]})


pl_df.groupby('key').agg([
    pl.col('col1').cumulative_eval(pl.element().mean()).suffix('_cummean')
]).explode(['col1_cummean'])

Out:
key     col1_cummean
1       1.0
1       1.5
1       2.0
2       1.0
2       1.0
2       1.0
3       2.0
3       2.5
3       3.0


pl_df.groupby('key').agg([
    pl.col('col2').cumulative_eval(pl.element().mean()).suffix('_cummean')
]).explode(['col2_cummean'])

Out:
PanicException: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: SchemaMisMatch(Borrowed("cannot unpack Series; data types don't match"))
```

I tried below expression

```
pl_df.select(pl.col('col2').cumulative_eval(pl.element().mean()).over('key'))
```

But same exception was occurred.

My expectation is like

```
pl_df.groupby('key').agg([
    pl.col('col2').cumulative_eval(pl.element().mean()).suffix('_cummean')
]).explode(['col2_cummean'])

Out:
key     col1_cummean
1       1.0
1       1.5
1       2.0
2       null
2       null
2       null
3       null
3       3.0
3       3.5
```

Comment: Oof. That's a Rust error that really shouldn't be directly reported to a Python user.

Comment: I can't tell if it should *be* an error for column 2 to be a mix of `int` values and `None`s, and the Python wrapper is just reporting it poorly, or if the library has a bug in handling `None`s.

Comment: This has been [reported as a bug on the issues tracker.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6394)

Comment: @jqurious you has already reported this bug on the issue? Thanks!

Comment: It has been fixed by https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/6435